# See Org Mode links in Org Mode comments

Tags: org-mode

If I have an `[[Org Mode Link]]` and then make that line a `# Comment [[Org Mode Link]]` the fontification changes and I can no longer tell that it is a link. Can this behavior be changed?

Comment: One thing you _can_ do is use the `#+BEGIN_COMMENT` and `#+END_COMMENT` commands as documented [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-lines.html). Of course, this isn't a perfect solution because it requires you to edit your document, and it's not as pretty visually.

Comment: Or better yet, a way to fontify not just org-mode style links, but make anything starting with http:// into an active hyperlink (i.e. such that org-return would follow the link).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can.

The function `org-set-font-lock-defaults` sets font lock defaults for org mode buffers for all the types of org faces.

Not only the contents itself is important but also the order in which it is defined.

FYI, I will show pieces of code from the actual function (org version 8.3.4):

This block takes care of fontifing links. The type of link you are interested in is fourth line ('bracket).

```
;; Links
(if (memq 'tag lk) '(org-activate-tags (1 'org-tag prepend)))
(if (memq 'angle lk) '(org-activate-angle-links (0 'org-link t)))
(if (memq 'plain lk) '(org-activate-plain-links (0 'org-link t)))
(if (memq 'bracket lk) '(org-activate-bracket-links (0 'org-link t)))
(if (memq 'radio lk) '(org-activate-target-links (1 'org-link t)))
(if (memq 'date lk) '(org-activate-dates (0 'org-date t)))
(if (memq 'footnote lk) '(org-activate-footnote-links))
```

The comment lines (meta lines) are taken care by following piece of code:

```
;; Blocks and meta lines
'(org-fontify-meta-lines-and-blocks))))
```

The most easy (but maybe also a hacky) way to do it is remove the "bracket" s-expression from the list `org-font-lock-extra-keywords` and add it to the end of the list.

You can do so using a hook named `org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook` to "swap" these.

I am now using this code:

```
(defun vlk/org-font-links-in-comments ()
  ;; get bracket link s-expression for the font lock
  (let ((bracket-link-face (nth 12 org-font-lock-extra-keywords)))
    ;; remove the font lock from the list
    (delete bracket-link-face org-font-lock-extra-keywords)
    ;; add it to the end
    (add-to-list 'org-font-lock-extra-keywords bracket-link-face t)))

(org-add-hook 'org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook 'vlk/org-font-links-in-comments)
```

It certainly can be improved but it is functional for me so far.

Comment: Seems like this is no longer working for current emacs 27.2 / org-mode 9.6.  Is there a recommended way to do this now?